# Select item in gridview without choice mode

Tags: android, gridview

If I would want select item onItemClick and remember, that it have been selected, how should I do that?
I tried

```
    gv.setNumColumns(controller.getGame().getField().getColumnsNumber());
    gv.setAdapter(controller.getGame().getField().getCellAdapter());
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    gv.setSelection(1);
```

OR

```
itemView.setSelected(true);
```

and just nothing is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a arraylist of boolean when you select write true otherwize false. And in getview function, Check if value for this item is true then show it is selected otherwize it is not.

Comment: How i can show that it is selected? I've already done something like this with  changing background ove the item view. I don't want to do that.